# using express-session to save session failed

Tags: express, express-session

I'm using Express-session in `/api/login` to save session . I was trying to add `count` (+1) but every time I got the same number `1`. And the browser didn't get `connect.sid` .The api code is following

```js
var app = new (require('express'))();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = 3060;
var session = require("express-session");

app.use(session({
  secret: 'sessiontest',
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/api/login',function(req,res,next){
    let sess = req.session;
    if(sess.count){
      sess.count++;
    }else{
      sess.count =1;
    }
    let result = {
        status: 'true',
        code: '1',
        msg: 'succ',
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        count: sess.count
    };

    console.log(result);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    res.json(result);
});

app.listen(port,function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } else {
    console.info("==>   API listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when accessing over http, the browser doesn't send the cookie, and the server thinks it's a new session.

Comment: I fixed this by changing the sesssion's cookie settings to `secure: process.env.NODE_ENV=="prod"`